# A photo in public domain enhanced by software, does that affect copyright?

Tags: copyright

I want to include public domain photos in a history book. If I use 3rd party software to enhance the image - does the software company own the rights of the altered image?

Comment: That would imply Adobe would own every image ever photoshopped ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, better read that EULA one more time. 

Comment: Generally, copyright belongs to the author/creator of a work, e.g. the artist, photographer, or company who commissioned the work. Whether or not you or anyone can claim copyright on alterations to a public domain image is a legal question I can't answer. Ask your lawyer. Please don't ask for legal advice here as it's off-topic.

Comment: Try Law Stack Exchange.

Comment: I once tried to ask how certain things had copyright or not. And basically the legal thinkers seem to think a bit disingeniously that copyright just is or is not. And you can not really know which ot is untill its stripped from you. In which case it never was. Untill then its always possible that later its discovered that it never was.

Comment: @joojaa It's simple. There are 2 things to know about it.

1. The author always remains the author even when the piece of work is sold and that's it. You created the work, you are the author.
2. Copyright is obtained by registering the creative works as copyright material at least where I live. You register an original of the creative work. In general you describe what exactly should not be used by others.
Photographers tend to think that they own copyright, because they are the author but that's not the case and I doubt it they bother registering their images as copyright material.

Comment: Most places dont have a registering process. And according to international treaties you dont have to. Problem with that is they can later decide its not copyrightable so it never had copyright.

Comment: Registration, at least in the US, is *not* required but merely *helpful* should a dispute arise.

Comment: @Komental - sorry but that's incorrect. Here in the UK at least it is possible to sell a copyright to a third party, for example to a client so that they can own the full rights. Also in the UK, copyright is automatically conferred to the creator of a work - this includes photography and virtually every creative art form.  Registration is available, but it's not a requirement for the purpose of claiming copyright.  Copyright laws can differ depending on jurisdiction, even though there are international conventions and treaties.

Comment: It's pretty much the same in the US @BillyKerr creator owns everything unless explicitly sold or given away. There's *never* any assumption that there is no copyright. And "Public domain" means... it's **public** domain. You can't claim copyright... but you can claim a derivative work copyright, I believe. -- but I'm **not** a lawyer.. which is really needed for definitive clarity.

Comment: Thanks all, (I didn't know legal issues were not allowed). I'm not seeking my own copyright but seeking to ensure I don't accidentally trip over somebody else's. I can see its tricky and will request consent from all the image software providers I use. Fingers crossed....